# Shibboleth Testshib IDP is not logging out When i browse "https://www.testshib.org/Shibboleth.sso/Logout"

Tags: shibboleth

I have installed Shibboleth SP in local. I am trying to test it with TestShib IDP. Ii was succeded to regiter with Testshib and able to login.

When i am trying to Logout from testshib IDP(https://www.testshib.org/Shibboleth.sso/Logout). It is giving [Status of Local Logout: Logout completed successfully.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjFrS.png)

But when i am trying to login again it is not asking for Login page it is automatically logging the user.

Can you please tell me solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well unfortunately there is no solution to this flow.

It is not in SP's hand to get user logged out. Shibboleth may keep session on or it is possible for idP to keep the session on.

So it is safe to keep in mind that it will never be logged out manually.